# How to read particular one file in mule using MEL?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

These all files downloaded from ftp.

[image]

I have tried this flow :

```
<flow name="myFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="fiel_path" connector-ref="File" pollingFrequency="3600000" fileAge="50000" responseTimeout="10000" encoding="UTF-16" mimeType="text/csv" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=".*#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy_MM_dd')].*.csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    ....
```

But I could not read file.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: change date formate in regex

Comment: MEL expressions are not evaluated in filename-regex-filter patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Include HH:mm:ss in regex

```
#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in regex filter pattern 
".*#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy_MM_dd_HH:mm:ss')].csv"

Answer (score 0):

The file regex pattern does not process MEL expressions.

You will have to change your filename-regex-filter pattern in your file inbound-endpoint and include an expression filter in your flow.

```
<file:inbound-endpoint path="fiel_path" connector-ref="File" pollingFrequency="3600000" fileAge="50000" responseTimeout="10000" encoding="UTF-16" mimeType="text/csv" doc:name="File">
    <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=".*\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}_.*.csv" caseSensitive="true"/>
</file:inbound-endpoint>

<expression-filter expression="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename.contains(server.dateTime.format('yyyy_MM_dd'))]" doc:name="Filter today's date Expression"/>
```

The above regex filter only allows those files with the dates in their filenames such as anytext_2016_05_10_anytext.csv.

The above expression filter only allows today's date through. I am assuming you only want today's date based on your use of the server.datetime in your regex.